# Plotting a contour map with row names/indices of dataframe as y-values

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

The following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)))
df.index = [1000, 200, 50, 1, 0.1]
```

Where the index are pressure levels indicating the altitude of the values.

When making a simple contour plot:

```
plt.contourf(df)
```

[image: plot]

The y-values don't correspond with the indices values. I would like to have the pressure levels which correspond to the indices values to be used as the values for the y-axis.

I tried using the extent parameter, but this stretches out the values between the min/max. Pressure levels aren't spread out evenly.

Comment: [contourf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) has another form `contourf(X,Y,df)` which you should use in your case.

Comment: Normally yes, but I only have index values. No Y list or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in the documentation of [**`matplotlib.pyplot.contourf`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html):

> **X, Y : *array-like, optional***
> The coordinates of the values in *Z*.
> *X* and *Y* must both be 2D with the same shape as *Z* (e.g. created via [**numpy.meshgrid**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid)), or they must both be 1-D such that `len(X) == N` is the number of columns in *Z* and `len(Y) == M` is the number of rows in *Z*.
> *X* and *Y* must both be ordered monotonically.
> If not given, they are assumed to be integer indices, i.e. `X = range(N)`, `Y = range(M)`.

So you can pass:

- `range(len(df.columns))` as `X`
- list of pressure levels, `[1000, 200, 50, 1, 0.1]`, as `Y`
- `df` as `Z`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5, 5)))

plt.contourf(range(len(df.columns)), [1000, 200, 50, 1, 0.1], df)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found it out myself as well yesterday:

retrieved the y-values from the index using list(df.index).

Then create an evenly spaced X value if you have any min/max values using np.linspace and take 2 off the total size of the pressure levels:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)))
df.index = [1000, 200, 50, 1, 0.1]


x_vals = np.linspace(min, max, size(df.index) -2))

plt.contourf(lat_vals, press_lvl, clim)
```